# Let $G $ be abelian group $N,H<G$ prove that $NH $ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Question:**

> Let $G $ be abelian group ,let  $N,H<G$
>   I need to prove that $NH:=\{nh\, ; \,n\in N,n\in H\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: The orders of $G$, $N$ and $H$ are irrelevant, so forget about them. You prove it is a subgroup in the usual way by proving that it is closed under multiplication and under taking inverses, and that it contains the identity. This is all routine checking - you just do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $G$ is abelian then every subgroup of $G$ is normal in $G$. Then as $N, H < G$ it follows that $NK < G$. In order to show the latter result, consider the following result

**Claim:** $NH$ is a subgroup of $G$ if, and only if, $NH = HN$.

Comment: If $G$ abelian so $NH=HN$?

Comment: No necessarily. If $y \in HN = NH$ then there exists $ h \in H$ and $n \in N$ such that $y = hn$, also there exists $n' \in N$ and $h' \in H$ such that $y = n'h'$, and not necessarily $n'= n$ and $h = h'$.